# Swapping ctrl and cmd key on centOS

Tags: mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I'm running CentOS 6.7 on virtual box 5.0.4 using a macbook air laptop.

I'd like to use the apple cmd key instead of ctrl just to make life easier for copying, pasting, etc..

How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it's pretty simple. You need to install guest additions and then change some keyboard layout settings. See details here:

http://blog.nostopbutton.com/2013/08/24/setup-copy-and-paste-between-os-x-and-linux-virtualbox/